# Cannot schema bind view MyName' because name MyTable is invalid for schema binding

Tags: sql-server, view

I am trying to create an indexed view in SQL Server 2012 on a query that has 10 joins (inner and left), which is accessed a lot.

However, when attempting to create the view, I get an error:

> Cannot schema bind view 'vw_transaction' because name 'entity_event'
>   is invalid for schema binding.

I am (attempting to) create the view using:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_transaction WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
    Select ee.id as entity_event_id,
        ....
```

Is there a reason for this error? It looks like it's a reserved word, as the error mentions a 'name', as opposed to a column. `Entity_event` is the name of my main table.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding the schema name in front of all table references:

```
select [..] from schema_name.table_name
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. But, woundering about this unique behaviour. In that case even select statement with only table name should not work.

Comment: Yes where schema binding is concerned you must provide both schema and table name and the objects must be in the database in which the view created is schema bound

Answer (score 10):

If your shop is like mine and each database consists only of tables with the default schema, just add `[dbo].` in front of each table name.

Answer (score 3):

Though the Question is very old but today I too faced the same issue.

My isssue got resolved by just removing the Database name fixes the issue.

```
select [..] from [Database].schema_name.table_name //giving error

select [..] from schema_name.table_name //removing Database fixed the error.
```

Hope this help for someone.